# SaltStack: Delete directory, if it is empty

Tags: saltstack

How can I delete a directory with SaltStack, if it is empty?

First I remove a file in this directory, and then I would like to delete the  directory. But if there is one or several files in the directory, then the directory should not be removed.

I checked the docs of [file.absent](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.absent) but found no solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **unless** (https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html)

```
/path/to/directory:
  file.absent:
    - unless: file.path_exists_glob('/path/to/directory/*')
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. Use unless instead of onlyif)